# Looping through object properties, one of which is an array (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm just beginning with JavaScript and I would like some help on a loop I need to perform. I have read many code snippets and this still seems foreign to me, and I would appreciate some guidance.

An object (car) has five properties, one of which is an array. I need to loop through the object and print each of those values. What is a good, simple way to do this--either using a single loop or a nested one? I've tried using a counter and using that value as an index number for the properties and the array, but haven't been successful. Again, I'm very new to this and so I haven't been able to relate my example to those I've read.

```
    var options = ["hard top", "power windows", "racing stripe", "fog 
    lights"];

    var car = {color: "red", make:"Chevrolet", model:"Camaro",  
    year:"1967", options};

    //I need a loop where with each iteration a property value of the  
    //car and an option is printed

    document.write(SOMETHING);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Also related: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop through each `key` (e.g. `color`, `make`, etc.) of your `car` object, and print the `key` and the `value`.

```
Object.keys(car).forEach(key => {
  console.log(key, car[key]);
});
```

Will output the following:

```
color red
make Chevrolet
model Camaro
year 1967
options [ 'hard top', 'power windows', 'racing stripe', 'fog lights' ]
```

Comment: According to the question it says `//I need a loop where with each iteration a property value of the  
    //car and an option is printed

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(car).forEach(function(key, idx) {
  if (key !== options) {
    console.log(car[key];
    console.log(car.options[idx]);
  }
}
```

This will print out on each iteration a property of the car and one of the car options which I believe was the requirement.

`Object.keys(car)` gives you an array of the car properties and then you iterate over each one. In this case a bit more complicated by wanting a property and an option on each loop.